# ntfs disk dying or..? rsync and mkdir failing, strange behavior

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, rsync, strace

## System

```
root@host:~# uname -a
Linux host 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

## Mounts

```
root@host:~# mount | tail -2
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/sda1 type ntfs (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask
=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1)
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/sdb1 type ntfs (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask
=077,nls=utf8,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1)
```

That make this permissions:

```
root@host:~# ls -l /mnt/sda1/tier1 | grep utils
drwx------ 1 user user 53248 Apr 27 09:44 utils
```

## The failing syncing

```
root@host:~# rsync -av --delete --progress /mnt/sdb1/tier1/utils/ /mnt/sda1/tier
1/utils/
sending incremental file list
file1
  1585040834 100%   39.53MB/s    0:00:38 (xfer#1, to-check=306/308)
file2
     9017075 100%   16.10MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=239/308)
dir1/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/dir1" failed: Operation not 
permitted (1)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
dir2/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/dir2" failed: Operation not 
permitted (1)
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/.file1.LbYXJw" failed: Permission denied (
13)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/.file2.ORT4HA" failed: Permission denied (
13)
sent 1594262488 bytes  received 127 bytes  54042800.51 bytes/sec
total size is 7349105657  speedup is 4.61
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 2
3) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]
```

## A directory creation try

```
root@host:~# mkdir /mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/foo
mkdir: cannot create directory `/mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/foo': Operation not permit
ted
root@host:~# strace mkdir /mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/foo
```

[Ommited part...]

```
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1539648, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1539648, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb74c7000
close(3)                                = 0
mkdir("/mnt/sda1/tier1/utils/foo", 0777) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7
7cc000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb77cc000, 4096)                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (
No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No 
such file or directory)
write(2, "mkdir: ", 7mkdir: )                  = 7
write(2, "cannot create directory `/mnt/sd"..., 51cannot create directory `/mnt/
sda1/tier1/utils/foo') = 51
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such 
file or directory)
write(2, ": Operation not permitted", 25: Operation not permitted) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
root@host:~# _
```

I already tried using `mount` with an umask value of 033, with identical consequences.

Comment: What do your smart stats say about your disk health? http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/monitoring-hard-disks-smart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the ntfs-3g package (if you haven't already), and mount it as type "ntfs-3g". The default ntfs drivers only mount disks readonly.